# C# list not populated by object

Tags: c#, list

I have been working on a home project and I have been getting an issue that I am missing the solution to.

I have created the following class

```
public class Sides
{
    //These are the encapsulated data 
    private int intAdj;         //adjacent
    private int intOpp;         //opposite
    private Double doubleHypot; //hypotenuse

    //This is the constructor 
    public Sides(int intAdj, int intOpp, Double doubleHypot)
    {
        //less confusion when the same name is used
        this.intAdj = intAdj;
        this.intOpp = intOpp;
        this.doubleHypot = doubleHypot;
    }

    //Getters and Setters
    public int IntAdj { get; set; }
    public int IntOpp { get; set; }
    public Double DoubleHypot { get; set; }
}
```

I am calling it from this Method

```
Sides mySide;
//This is where the calculations occur
for (int indexAdj = 1; indexAdj < (intTriangleSize + 1); indexAdj++)
{
    for (int indexOpp = 1; indexOpp < (intTriangleSize + 1); indexOpp++)
    {
        doubleHypotenuse = doubHypot(doubleSquare(indexAdj), doubleSquare(indexOpp));
        mySide = new Sides(indexAdj, indexOpp, doubleHypotenuse);
        MessageBox.Show("Green Lantern" + "\n"
            + "Adjacent " + indexAdj + "\n"
            + "Opposite " + indexOpp + "\n"
            + "Hypotenuse " + doubleHypotenuse);
        listTriangle.Add(mySide);
    }
}
```

And the declaring and initialising of the List is as follows

```
private List<Sides> listTriangle;
listTriangle = new List<Sides>();
```

Through trial and error, The values that should populate the list are correct as you can see in the image attached here
[image: Inputting of the List]

I immediately then try to check the list through this code by cycling through a loop to check to see if is working.
The code is

```
for (int indexRan = 0; indexRan < listTriangle.Count; indexRan++)
{
    if (indexRan == 2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(listTriangle[2].IntAdj + " Purple Haze");
    }
}
```

This results in the following image
[image]

I would be grateful and appreciate any help and guidance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're assigning to the private fields in the constructor, rather than the public properties that are being accessed from the caller.

One way to avoid this is to just use public properties:

```
public class Sides
{
    // Public properties
    public int Adjacent { get; set; }
    public int Opposite { get; set; }
    public double Hypotenuse { get; set; }

    // Constructor 
    public Sides(int adjacent, int opposite, double hypotenuse)
    {
        this.Adjacent = adjacent;
        this.Opposite = opposite;
        this.Hypotenuse = hypotenuse;
    }
}
```

If you want to only allow setting the properties from within the class itself, you can make the setter `private`:

```
public class Sides
{
    // Public read-only properties
    public int Adjacent { get; private set; }
    public int Opposite { get; private set; }
    public double Hypotenuse { get; private set; }

    // Constructor 
    public Sides(int adjacent, int opposite, double hypotenuse)
    {
        this.Adjacent = adjacent;
        this.Opposite = opposite;
        this.Hypotenuse = hypotenuse;
    }
}
```

Also note that it is not necessary to include the `type` in a variable's name.

Comment: An historical note: Including the type as a prefix to variable names is known as "Hungarian Notation" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).  It was very popular in the 1990s, but has since fallen out of fashion.  It was particularly called out as something to avoid in the style guides that accompanied the initial .NET Framework releases.

Comment: Thanks Flydog57 for the comment. I was using this method to keep a track of what is happening during the construction process. I am not that confident in programming but slowly. Thank you and Rufus L